# Erro ao fazer chamada ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou tentando fazer a seguinte chamada ajax:

```js
function salvarAposta() {

    var nomeApostador = $('#nomeApostador').val();
    var jogosSelecionados = $('#tabelaFinalizacao tbody tr');
    var valorAposta = parseFloat($('#valor_aposta').val());
    var valorRetorno = parseFloat($('#valor_retorno').val());
    var listaApostas = new Array();

    if (!nomeApostador) {
        alert('Informe o nome do apostador!');
        return false;
    }

    jogosSelecionados.each(function() {
        listaApostas.push($(this).data('key'));
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http:/localhost/projetos/centraljogos/webservice/aposta.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            nomeApostador: nomeApostador, 
            valorAposta: valorAposta, 
            valorRetorno: valorRetorno, 
            listaApostas:listaApostas
        },
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "success"){
                alert('Aposta salva com sucesso!');                
            }
            else{
                alert('aposta -> Não foi possível salvar a aposta!');
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert('aposta -> Ocorreu um erro ao se comunicar com o servidor! Por favor, entre em contato com o administrador ou tente novamente mais tarde.');
        }
    });
}
```

Aqui é o que tenho em 'aposta.php':

```
<?php echo 'success'; ?>
```

A função me retorna o 'error' ao invés do 'success', o que é engraçado pois eu faço outras chamadas com a mesma estrutura e funciona. Ah, a url tá correta. Se alguém puder me dar uma mão agradeço.

Comment: já ativou as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e inspecionou os dados da request feita?

Comment: Complementando o que @fernandosavio disse, dê console.log(err); e cole o resultado na pergunta. Essa requisição AJAX retorna qual código HTTP? Já verificou se alguma exceção é lançada no backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu ajax você espera um json, mas na sua função php está retornando um echo (ou seja, um HTML com success no body).

Acredito que se fizer assim irá funcionar:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['success']);
exit;
```

Comment: Era exatamente este detalhe que estava faltando, pois eu já tinha feito isso nas outras funções e tinha deixado passar despercebido nessa. Obrigado, companheiro!